# Problem with askopenfilename() sending to converting function and saving file using asksavefile() - Python Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I wrote a CAD coordinate conversion application that reads a .txt file using filedialok.askopenfilename() using the function read_file_click().
After selecting the appropriate scale in the Combobox, the program converts the file using the convert() function, then saves it to a .txt file after calling the function save_file_click().
The problem is that when I send the returned value from the convert function to the save_file_click() function, I get two notifications about opening the file.
I don't know how to correct this error. I tried using global variables, but it doesn't help, and weak errors appears with the data_list_no_head variable. Thanks for help:)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = Tk()
root.title("Autocad Coordinate Converter")
root.geometry("")
root.geometry("280x320")
root.resizable(False, False)


def combo_sets():
    scale_combo.set("")


def ending_message():
    messagebox.showinfo("Autocad Coordinate Converter", "End")


def read_file_click():
    global data_list_no_head
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    return file_path


def convert():
    file_path_new = read_file_click()
    data_list = []
    with open(file_path_new, encoding='utf-16') as file:
        for line in file:
            data_list.append(line.split())
    data_list_no_head = data_list[4:]
    return data_list_no_head

def save_file_click():
    new = convert()
    scale_get = scale_combo.get()
    data = None
    event_eng = None
    cal = None
    x_coordinate = None
    y_coordinate = None

    output_file = open(output_file_path_name, 'a')
    if scale_get == "1:500" or scale_get == "1:1000":
        for event in new:
            for _ in event:
                data = event[1]
                event_eng = event[4]
                x_coordinate = event[5]
                y_coordinate = event[6]
                cal = int(event_eng[-1])*2-2

            output_file.write(f"_layer u w{data[2:4]}e{event_eng[-1]}  _donut 0 {cal} {y_coordinate},"
                              f"{x_coordinate} \n")
        output_file.close()
        new_file_name = output_file_path_name[:-4] + ".scr.txt"
        os.rename(output_file_path_name, new_file_name)
        combo_sets()

        ending_message()
    elif scale_get == "1:2000":
        for event in new:
            for _ in event:
                data = event[1]
                event_eng = event[4]
                x_coordinate = event[5]
                y_coordinate = event[6]
                cal = 2*(int(event_eng[-1])*2-2)

            output_file.write(f"_layer u w{data[2:4]}e{event_eng[-1]}  _donut 0 {cal} {y_coordinate},"
                              f"{x_coordinate} \n")
        output_file.close()
        new_file_name = output_file_path_name[:-4] + ".scr.txt"
        os.rename(output_file_path_name, new_file_name)
        combo_sets()
        ending_message()
    elif scale_get == "1:5000":
        for event in new:
            for _ in event:
                data = event[1]
                event_eng = event[4]
                x_coordinate = event[5]
                y_coordinate = event[6]
                cal = 5*(int(event_eng[-1])*2-2)

            output_file.write(f"_layer u w{data[2:4]}e{event_eng[-1]}  _donut 0 {cal} {y_coordinate},"
                              f"{x_coordinate} \n")
        output_file.close()
        new_file_name = output_file_path_name[:-4] + ".scr.txt"
        os.rename(output_file_path_name, new_file_name)
        combo_sets()
        ending_message()
    elif scale_get == "1:10000":
        for event in new:
            for _ in event:
                data = event[1]
                event_eng = event[4]
                x_coordinate = event[5]
                y_coordinate = event[6]
                cal = 20*(int(event_eng[-1])-2)

            output_file.write(f"_layer u w{data[2:4]}e{event_eng[-1]}  _donut 0 {cal} {y_coordinate},"
                              f"{x_coordinate} \n")
        output_file.close()
        new_file_name = output_file_path_name[:-4] + ".scr.txt"
        os.rename(output_file_path_name, new_file_name)
        combo_sets()
        ending_message()


# Frame1
frame1 = LabelFrame(root, padx=15, pady=15, relief=FLAT)
frame1.grid(row=1, column=0)

button_1 = Button(frame1, text="Read .txt file", padx=15, pady=15, width=20, height=1, command=read_file_click)
button_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=3, pady=3)
# Frame2
frame2 = LabelFrame(root, padx=15, pady=15, relief=FLAT)
frame2.grid(row=2, column=0)

Label(frame2, text="Select scale:", width=14).grid(row=1, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)

scale_combo = ttk.Combobox(frame2, values=["1:500", "1:1000", "1:2000", "1:5000", "1:10000"], width=9, state='readonly')
scale_combo.current()
scale_combo.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)
# Frame3
frame3 = LabelFrame(root, padx=50, pady=50, relief=FLAT)
frame3.grid(row=3, column=0)

button_2 = Button(frame3, text="Save file in CAD format", padx=15, pady=15, width=20, height=1,
                  command=save_file_click)

button_2.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=3, pady=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you're seeing an error message, please include the error traceback with your question.

Comment: `output_file_path_name` in `save_file_click()` is not defined.